# Is there a name for this identity involving series?

Tags: sequences-and-series, terminology

I'm working through Spivak's Calculus, and for one of the problems I had to prove the Scharwz inequality. I derived this identity, and was wondering if this had a name, it seemed quite important. It's factoring the first sums into to squared terms:

$$\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_i^2\sum_{i=1}^{n}y_i^2 \equiv \left (\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_i y_i\right)^2 + \sum_{i=1}^{n-1}\left(\sum_{j=i+1}^{n}(x_i y_j - x_j y_i)^2 \right)$$

Here's an example when $n = 4$, because the identity is a bit unnerving, at least to me:

$$(x_1^2 + x_2^2 + x_3^2 + x_4^2)(y_1^2 + y_2^2 + y_3^2 + y_4^2) = (x_1 y_1 + x_2 y_2 + x_3 y_3 + x_4 y_4)^2 + (x_1 y_2 - x_2 y_1)^2 + (x_1 y_3 - x_3 y_1)^2 + (x_1 y_4 - x_4 y_1)^2 \\ + (x_2 y_3 - x_3 y_2)^2 + (x_2 y_4 - x_4 y_2)^2 \\ + (x_3 y_4 - x_4 y_3)^2$$

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is called [Lagrange's identity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange%27s_identity).

Answer (score 2):

The special case $n=4$ that you gave is [Euler's Four Square Identity.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_four-square_identity)

The version given in the above link is not quite the same as the one you quote. In fact the one you quote is Euler's *original* Four Square Identity. It plays a crucial role in the proof that every positive integer is the sum of four squares. The modified version of the link (which is obtained simply by changing the sign of $x_1$) fits in better with the use of the identity to show that the norm of a product of two quaternions is the product of the norms.

Comment: They're similar, but not the same, as far as I can tell.